# Can you extend a textview to change the color of the margin?

Tags: java, android, textview

Is there  a way to extend a textview to change the color of the left margin to a different color than the first of the textview?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, post with some image or sample code.

Comment: How about creating custom **stateList (Drawables)**.. Why extending TextView

Comment: Do you maybe just mean a linear color gradient ?

Comment: **margin color** has no relation with `TextView` , it has relation with the **background color** of the parentLayout of your `TextView`, so you need to create a **Custom Layout(Linear or Relative ...)** and inside it try to create a `TextView` , and then specify the color you want as a background of your `Layout`, and apply the `leftMargin` value to the `TextView`